# Public Access of Template Value

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following:

```
template<int T>
class Test {
public:
    constexpr static int A = T;
};

int main(int argsc, char** args) {
    std::cout << Test<2>::T << std::endl; // Option 1
    std::cout << Test<2>::A << std::endl; // Option 2
}
```

Why doesn't option 1 compile? It seems that the `static constexpr A` is just an extra step. Is it that `T` isn't available publicly?

**Is there a cleaner way to get at `T` than by creating a publicly accessible member like `A` above?**

Comment: You cannot access the template parameters outside of the class.

Comment: @plasmacel — why is that true? The step of creating `A` seems unnecessary.

Comment: You can also create a trait which allow to retrieve template parameter. `template <typename> TestTrait; template <int N> TestTrait<Test<N>> struct { constexpr static int value = N; };`

Comment: @Jack I can't see another reason than because the standard says that.

Comment: `T` is just a name, and you are allowed to use different names afterward: `template <int T>struct Test;` and then `template <int N>struct Test{};` is legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't option 1 compile?

Because a template parameter is just the name of a parameter. You're allowed to rename them, that is:

```
template <class T> struct X;

// refers to same X
template <class U> struct X { ... };

// still the same X
template <class V>
void X<V>::foo() { ... };
```

For the same reason that you're allowed to name your function parameters differently between the declaration and definition. Requiring the name of the template parameter to be automatically visible within the class template would mean it would have to be fixed at first go.

> Is there a cleaner way to get at T than by creating a publicly accessible member like A above?

Creating the publicly accessible member is usually the way to go. Alternatively, you can create an external trait:

```
template <class T> struct X { using type = T; }; // internal

template <class > struct get_type;
template <class T> struct get_type<X<T>> { using type = T; }; // external
```

Comment: Does `using type = T` work if `type` is not a type but an `int` value?

Comment: @Jack No, you'd have to have `static constexpr int value = T;` I just use types because types are more typical.

Comment: Need to mention that the feature that you can rename the parameters outside of the class wouldn't rule out the feature to access the parameters by their original name, or extract them by their index. So it's more like a limitation by the standard.